# Practical use of semi direct product of group in Cryptography

Tags: rsa, group-theory

Is there any example of semi-direct product used in any of cryptographic application? Does it help in choosing integers p, q in RSA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public key exchange using semidirect productof (semi)groups by Habeeb et al

https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/226.pdf